# How to pass button title to label in different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

On a new project, I have 2 view controllers (View1 and View2).
I have a button in View1 and a label in View2. 
When I press this button in View1, I want the name/title of the button to appear in the label on View2 when I am transferred to the View2 page. 
How can I do this?

I checked this page but didn't really understand: [Passing button title to a new view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385876/passing-button-title-to-a-new-view)

Comment: what didn't you understand about it?

Comment: I got errors when I typed them in.

Comment: that's because they're in obj-c, not swift - but do you understand the principle that the answer is trying to explain about how you should approach the problem?

Comment: I don't quite understand the "you need to create a property" bit

Comment: that exposes the label on the second view so you can pass it information

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/2535467

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Are you using storyboard? There are 2 ways to handle this.....I would like to know if the button you will tap will perform a segue ???

Comment: @CaptJak As you said, it is a duplicate. Just in a different language. I don't have enough experience with programming to understand it in Objective C and convert it to Swift.

Comment: See: stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/2535467. It's in swift.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new CocoaTouch Class `SecondViewController`, subclassing `UIViewController` including `XIB` and create `IBOutlet` for the `label`

Declare a variable:

`var labelTitle: String!` in `SecondViewController`

SecondViewController ViewDidLoad will look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            titleLabel.text = labelTitle
}

// Whereas titleLabel is the UILabel Outlet connected from XIB
```

Now in your `FirstViewController`, on your button Tapped action

add the following

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender : UIButton) {
    // If the VCs are in a storyboard you will need to get the storyboard to access them
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) as UIStoryboard
    let secondVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    secondVC.labelTitle = sender.titleLabel?.text

    // If not do this
    let secondVC = SecondViewController.init(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    secondVC.labelTitle = sender.titleLabel?.text
}

//Next present or push your ViewController
```

Comment: How do I assign labelTitle to my UILabel?

Comment: Thank you so much! For the code in FirstViewController, I keep getting a "expected declaration" error on the second line.

Comment: and what is "button tapped action"?

Comment: button tapped action is IBAction on the button. please check the edited answer

Comment: You could also do it with a segue, no?

Comment: Thanks again for your response! Now I get "Value of type "UIButton" has no member "label(title of label)".

Comment: @CaptJak is there a way to pass button title info to another viewcontroller using segue?

Answer (score -1):

**- On View2 create property for accepting button title**

```
@interface View2 : UIViewController {

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *btnTitle;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   self.lblTitle.text = self.btnTitle;
}
```

**In View1**

```
  @interface View1 : UIViewController {

    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;

    - (void)myButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    View1 *newViewController = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:'View1' bundle:nil];
    newViewController.btnTitle = self.btn.titleLabel.text;

    // push or present controller

    }
```